# creating a database table using very large csv in python

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

and i have a very large csv file with delimiter "|" to create a table in db.First 5 lines of csv is given below

```
"Tha Twilight New Moon DVDrip 2009 XviD-AMiABLE"|694554360|2cae2fc76d110f35917d5d069282afd8335bc306|0|movies|0|1
"[RiP] Burn Up!"|734636626|f80762eb595c286b765848d13074247ee6a90d8c|2|other|0|0
"%5BA-Flux%26Lunar%5D  Hunter x Hunter Episodes 1-5 %5BDVD%5D"|1094189056|b639c563d665c1f2827a815267033724abfe4f4f|5|anime|0|0
"Hack SIGN 1-25 extra eps -aak-"|6258485500|8eb275e544913bd3255fd4781f058c3f2f98f77e|27|other|0|0
"Hunter X Hunter - 11-15 [A-K]"|971266048|ce07cc4a4da8e00e1c4972278d6e14b3049bb5cf|5|anime|0|0
```

and my required fields are also given below

```
    CREATE TABLE torrents (
  name TEXT,
  size DATE,
  hash TEXT UNIQUE,
  downloads_count TEXT,
  category TEXT,
  seeders INTEGER,
  leechers INTEGER
);

.mode csv
.separator "|"
.import torrents_mini.csv torrents
```

please suggest better and fast way to create this table into a database ?

Comment: @IanAuld, your comment is pretty pedantic and not very helpful.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far; include your code.

Comment: Can you please specify, where you need help. I can't figure out your specific problem.

Comment: @ron.rothman Not really. If he had a CSV file he could use the csv module. Since he doesn't, he can't. Also wea ren't answering these questions only for the OP, if someone in the future finds this questions that does have a CSV file this question won't be much of a help.

Comment: @IanAuld, FYI the `csv` module can use any delimiter, not just a comma.  `reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')`

Comment: Actually, yes, one would often refer to this as a CSV file (which, generically, refers to just about single-character-delimited file format like this), and it can be handled by the Python `csv` module by specifying the appropriate `delimiter` keyword.  Consider `w = csv.reader(open('/etc/passwd'), delimiter=':')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('navjod.db')
c = conn.cursor()
# Create table name | size | hash | downloads_count | category_id* | seeders | leechers
c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS torrents")
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE torrents
             (name TEXT, size TEXT, hash TEXT UNIQUE, downloads_count TEXT,
                category TEXT, seeders INTEGER, leechers INTEGER)''')

with open('sample.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    for i in spamreader:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO torrents VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", i)

conn.commit()
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: How is that different from what the `sqlite3` tool does?